# No reproducir video cuando se cierre modal

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

Cordial Saludo.

Tengo un modal con materialize css y dentro de el muestro un video, lo que sucede es que al cerrar el modal el video se queda reproduciendo por debajo, necesito que cuando el modal este cerrado el video no se reprodusca.

He probado varios códigos y no me han funcionado.

Gracias.

```html
<!-- MODAL DE MATERIALIZE -->

<div id="Video_Modal" class="modal mdl_general modal-video">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <video class="video_modal" id="video" src="Videos/VideoCronos.mp4" autoplay controls>
                    Tu navegador no soporta el elemento <code>video</code>
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Cerrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrias usar algo de javascript, jquery:

```
$('#Video_Modal').modal({
      dismissible: true,
      onCloseEnd: function() { 
        console.log('modal cerrada'); 
        //apunto al ID  de mi video 
        var vid = document.getElementById("video_modal"); 
        //pauso el video
        vid.pause(); 
      } 
    }
  );
```

Espero te sirva..!!

Tambien podrias usar algo de jquery para pausar el video:

```
$('#video_modal').trigger('pause');
```

Para mayor referencia : [options Modal](https://materializecss.com/modals.html#options)

Comment: No me funciona al cerrar el modal se escucha aun el audio por debajo y la reproducción permanece.

Comment: deberias agregar tu codigo para ver como esta y poder ayudarte..!!

Comment: agregue el modal que uso con materialize

Comment: podrias probar con el campo que lo hice..!!

Comment: Ya lo he realizo y de igual forma el video se sigue reproduciendo por debajo

Comment: Cuando le doy al Boton Cerrar el video sigue escunchandose por debajo

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto donde muestra como detectar el evento de cerrar modal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584601/5215609

Comment: Ya lo solucionaste?

Answer (score 0):

Logre darle solución creando una función por JS que matara la acción con el siguiente código.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function stopVideo() {
        document.getElementById('video').pause();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que al cerra el modal, el video se reproduce de fondo,
para solucionar este problema puedes utilizar jquery. 
debes programar el boton cerrar, al hacer click en el boton cerrar eliminas el src del iframe de la siguiente manera:

````
$('.close-modal').click(() => {
$('.myFrame').removeAttr('src');
});```
````

ahora si vas al navegador y recargas vera que se cierra el modal y se cierra el video,
pero si haces click en la referencia que dispara el modal, se desplegara el modal pero no se reproducira el video porque lo removimos hace un momento. Para dar solucion a este tema 
debes programar el enlace que llamama al modal de la siguiente manera:

```
$('.ImgVideo').click(() => {
$('.myFrame').attr('src', 'assets/Video/CuentoZlatan.mp4');
$("#ex1 ").modal({
escapeClose: false,
clickClose: false,
showClose: false
});
});
```